# how to send mail using SendGrid Api Key in azure portal using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, sendgrid

```
//in class a create object to classb and send data to classb sendmail method

class a{
classb b=new classb();
b.sendmail(jsonData);

}


// classb class recevie data and send the mail

class classb(){

//method
public void sendmail(classname obj){

        string to = "test.123@gmail.com";
        string from = "test@mail";
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
        message.Subject = "Demo Requsted from User";
        message.Body = mailbody;
        message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;

// where to give azure api key .i have only send-grid api key .please help me

        var smtp = new SmtpClient
        {
            Host = "smtp.sendgrid.net",// azure server
            Port = 587,
            EnableSsl = false,
            DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mail", "pwd")
        };

        try
        {
            smtp.Send(message);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;


        }

}
}
```

Comment: A tip, people who hang out here are experienced seasoned programmers, most of us have severe OCD and hate messy code and spend our lives trying to make things look neat and elegant. if you ask a question spend 5 minutes tidying your code for your press the big button, you'll always find it worth while

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you aren't using *SendGrid*  at all, you are using `SmtpClient`

If you want to use *SendGrid* you will need to download the nugets and write *SendGrid* code, none of what you is.

Please have a look through the following for examples and the nuget package

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Code_Examples/v2_Mail/csharp.html

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp

Comment: @TheGenral thank you your response  var myMessage = new SendGrid.SendGridMessage();
sendgridemsg (); geting error this method and i added  nugets and write sendgrid code also but same error

Comment: public void redemomail(adddemoreq body)
        {
   

            string mailbody = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filename);
            mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##Demotype##", body.Demotype);
            mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##Username##", body.Username);
            mailbody = mailbody.Replace("##Useremail##", body.Useremail);

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SendGridClient` class to send mail by `SendGrid` and then pass apiKey as a parameter into it

```
        static async Task Execute()
        {
            var apiKey = // your key
            var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
            var msg = new SendGridMessage()
            {
                From = new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "DX Team"),
                Subject = "Hello World from the SendGrid CSharp SDK!",
                PlainTextContent = "Hello, Email!",
                HtmlContent = "<strong>Hello, Email!</strong>"
            };
            msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("test@example.com", "Test User"));
            var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        }
```

For more details see here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sendgrid-dotnet-how-to-send-email

Comment: static async Task Execute()
how to get data from CLass A .in this method.

Comment: You just need to call this method like 'Execute.Wait();' from your method

Comment: okay but in classa class we send data to classb send-mail() method -its like parameters passing.

Comment: You can add same parameters in this method as well as use them